# Kubernetes Cluster | Unable to launch the application using Master Node

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have two Virtual Machines (Linux-Ubuntu) on Microsoft Azure one as a master node and other as a worker node. In my kubernetes cluster I have deployed a Nginx server which has been assigned to worker Node.

The problem is I am able to access the Nginx server on worker node ip i.e using command: **curl ip_address_of_Nginx_pod** but when I try to run the same command on Master Node its not working.

There is some issue with Inbound Rules I think. However I have already allowed all traffic on both master and worker node.

## On Master Node:

Once I run **Command**: kubectl get pods

```
NAME         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE              
myfirstpod   1/1     Running   1          23h   192.168.2.10   demo-my-worker
```

Once I run **Command**: curl 192.168.2.10 , It does not display anything...

```
root@Demo-my-master:~/demo# curl 192.168.2.10
```

## On Worker Node:

Once I run **Command**: curl 192.168.2.10, it runs perfectly fine.

```
root@Demo-my-worker:~/demo# curl 192.168.2.10


<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
body {
    width: 35em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed 
and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Can please someone help here and let me know why I am not able to get the same result on master node ?

yaml file I used to create Pod contains a simple Nginx server:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myfirstpod
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx:latest
```

Comment: how did you setup kubernetes? how did you configure service for the pod?

Comment: I set up kubernetes using kubeadm. Once the cluster is in ready state, I created a simple myfirst.yaml file which have a image of Nginx server. Once I created the pod using yaml file, cluster assigned the worker node to run this Pod. To run it locally without exposing to external world, I ran curl command which is working on worker node but not on master node.

Comment: probably means your networking is not setup correctly. did kubeadm create resource on azure or not? i'm exactly familiar with that tool

Comment: kubeadm will create resources on azure ? What exactly you mean by that ?

Comment: I am able to ping from master to worker node and also both nodes are in ready state. And coredns pod is running on master node.

Comment: that doesnt prove anything. i suspect the networking is off

Comment: Networking is off ? You mean on cluster or Azure Portal ?

Comment: off - means misconfigured.

Comment: Can you try first exposing it as service and then access using service name and port?

Comment: @PrateekJain Yes I tried that as well. In this case also I am able access the application on worker node only not on master node. Or from outside using worker node ip only I am able to access it not using master node ip.

Comment: I guess you just can connect the pod from the node which hosts it. You can try to create a service and set the pod as its backend. Then you can connect the pod through the node IP with the node port which the service exposed.

Comment: looks like issue with CNI plugin installation. can you try re-installing it?

Comment: @CharlesXu Thank you for helping here. But we can connect the pod from the node which hosts it as well as master node. Because I am able to connect the Pod from all nodes in cluster on GCP. But on Azure VM's I am facing this issue.

Comment: @PrateekJain I have followed the same steps on GCP and its working fine there. And I am able to access the Pod from all nodes in cluster. But it seems there is some problem with Azure security groups.